# Assigning a value to JSON Array

Tags: json, c++builder

I have a JSON Array "Screens" look like this:

[image: JsonFile]

I can get values this way :

```
   std::unique_ptr<TStringStream> FileContent(new TStringStream);
       FileContent->LoadFromFile(TOUCHGFXREADER_Params.ProjectFullPath);
       TJSONObject* tgfxFile = (TJSONObject*)TJSONObject::ParseJSONValue(FileContent->DataString);
       TJSONObject* Application  = (TJSONObject*)TJSONObject::ParseJSONValue(tgfxFile->GetValue("Application")->ToString());
       TJSONObject* Ekranlar = (TJSONArray*)TJSONObject::ParseJSONValue(Application->GetValue("Screens")->ToString());
       for(int i= 0; i<Ekranlar->Count ; i++ ){
           String name = Ekranlar->operator[](i)->ToString();
       }
```

But I can't assign new value to this array.

Comment: What value do you want to assign exactly? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you are over-using the `TJSONObject::ParseJSONValue()` method. You should be using it only to parse the `TStringStream` text. Once you have the top-level `TJSONObject*` (which BTW, you need to free when you are done using it), you don't need to keep calling `ParseJSONValue()` to access its child objects. You are already calling `TJSONObject::GetValue()` to access the objects as `TJSONValue*` pointers, just *type-cast* those pointers as needed, eg:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<TStringStream> FileContent(new TStringStream);
FileContent->LoadFromFile(TOUCHGFXREADER_Params.ProjectFullPath);
std::unique_ptr<TJSONValue> tgfxFile(TJSONObject::ParseJSONValue(FileContent->DataString));
if (tgfxFile) {
    TJSONObject* Object = static_cast<TJSONObject*>(tgfxFile.get());
    TJSONObject* Application = static_cast<TJSONObject*>(Object->GetValue(_D("Application")));
    TJSONArray* Screens = static_cast<TJSONArray*>(Application->GetValue(_D("Screens")));
    for(int i = 0; i < Screens->Count; i++){
        TJSONObject *ScreenObj = static_cast<TJSONObject*>(Screens->Item[i]);
        // use ScreenObj as needed...
    }
}
```

Now, that being said, you can manipulate a `TJSONArray` to add new elements (`TJSONArray::Add()` and `TJSONArray::AddElement()`), and to remove elements (`TJSONArray::Remove()`), but you cannot replace an element with a new value.  You would have to remove the desired element and then insert a new element.

If you just want to alter the contents of an existing object in the array, you already have access to the `TJSONObject*` pointer for each element, so you can manipulate those objects as needed, ie by using `TJSONObject:AddPair()`, `TJSONObject::RemovePair()`, etc.

However, modifying existing values in a `TJSONObject` is a bit tricky.  Delphi's JSON framework is not designed to *modify* existing values, only for reading documents and building new documents.  You can ask `TJSONObject` to give you a `TJSONValue*` for a desired child value, then type-cast it to the appropriate type (`TJSONString*`, `TJSONNumber*`, etc) and read from its respective property (`TJSONString::Value`, `TJSONNumber::AsInt`, etc), eg:

```cpp
bool override = static_cast<TJSONBool*>(ScreenObj->GetValue(_D("OverrideDefaultBufferSize")))->AsBoolean;
```

But you can't assign a new value to it.

So, the only way to *modify* a value in a `TJSONObject` is to either:

- remove the desired value via `TJSONObject::RemovePair()`, and then insert a new value of the same name using `TJSONObject::AddPair()`.

```cpp
ScreenObj->RemovePair(_D("OverrideDefaultBufferSize"));
ScreenObj->AddPair(_D("OverrideDefaultBufferSize"), new TJSONBool(...));
```

- ask the `TJSONObject` for the `TJSONPair` that holds the value you want, and then assign its `jsonValue` property to point at a new value of the desired type. Be sure to free the old value, or else it will be leaked.

```cpp
TJSONPair *pair = ScreenObj->Get(_D("OverrideDefaultBufferSize"));
TJSONValue *old = pair->jsonValue;
pair->jsonValue = new TJSONBool(...);
delete old;
```